# architecture x86_64 error in installing AVR development platform for mac

Tags: c, macos, gcc, embedded, arduino

I tried to install AVR development platform for mac from this site

http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/setup-mac.html
 **Option 3. Old style, 'by hand' compilation**

But I have an Error, Here is the error

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [cc1] Error 1

make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

is anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not setting your compiler to the `avr-gcc` you've (presumably) built. Set: 
`CC=arv-gcc` in your shell, or pass it to a configure script with:
`env CC=avr-gcc ./configure ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just try another **AVR** that works in the other mac, I had this problem and it's working for me now.